# Strategies to test whether the printed data are placed at the correct position

Tags: windows-7, printer, printing

I have a template on which I am printing data from my application. The below image explains the page better
[image: Sample Image of the page to be print]

The printing is done by a dot matrix printer and the sheet already has the layout of the page in it. My job is to fill the data at the places highlighted in yellow to the page. So **positioning is very important**. Right now I am taking many printouts to check the alignments and positioning. I would have been much better off if my *Print Preview* shows the page in it without the data. ( Just a thought )

So, I would like to know the strategies employed on printing pages that already has a template in it. What method should I adopt?

Answer (score 0):

There is software available that you can use with a scanner to scan the document.  The software then detects the empty fields on the page, and allows you to populate them with your data.  I believe I have done this with [ReadIRIS](http://www.irislink.com/c2-646-189/I-R-I-S----OCR-software-and-Document-Management-solutions.aspx).